# Weird PHP Google Maps Embed Behavior in an Iframe

Tags: php, google-maps, iframe, maps

I tried to embed google maps basing on addresses.

```
<iframe src="<?= $map_src ?>" width="500" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

The map DOES show when I use this address:

```
$map_src = "https://www.google.ca/maps?q=spa810+33535 Peachtree Rd. NE, Suite 530+Atlanta+GA&z=17&iwloc=near&output=embed";
```

However, when I try to use a different one. It shows the error

```
$map_src = "https://www.google.ca/maps?q=spa810+32222+McKinney+Ave+#120+Dallas+TX&z=17&iwloc=near&output=embed";

Refused to display 'https://www.google.ca/maps?q=spa810+2222+McKinney+Ave+#120+Dallas+TX&z=17&iwloc=near&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

I am not really sure what happens in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "#120" caused this issue. I replaced "**#120" by "Suite 120"** and it works fine!